# Programming a Cipher Program (Plain Text->Caesar Cipher->ASCII)?

Tags: java, ascii, encryption

I really need to know how you would code this or something similar in Java:
http://www.cs.carleton.edu/faculty/adalal/teaching/f05/107/applets/ascii.html

Here is my attempt I've been at it the whole day (literally) and have had to search on how to do it on the internet because but because my Java knowledge not so great I can't understand any (At the start of today I didn't know anything to do with arrays) of it all I need is a little help or a push in the right direction.

[edit] Sorry forgot to point out the question. What I'm having trouble with is not converting and ciphering the PlainText but trying to convert a encoded message (ciphered with my program of course) to PlainText (i.e I can't just reverse it with the variable in my program I actually have to be able to read it and decode it)

```
private void encryptBUTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)    
{                                           
    int encryptLength=encryptTXT.getText().length();
    int[] anArray=new int[encryptLength];
    String key=encryptKey.getText();
    if(key.isEmpty())
    {
        decryptTXT.setText(""+"INVALID KEY");
    }
    else
    {
        int key2=Integer.parseInt(key);
        for(int i=0;i<encryptLength;i++)
        {
            int letter = encryptTXT.getText().toLowerCase().charAt(i);
            System.out.println(letter);
            System.out.println((char)letter);
            int letterCiphered= (letter-key2);
            anArray[i]=letterCiphered;
        }
        String output=(Arrays.toString(anArray));
        decryptTXT.setText(output);
    }
}                                          

private void clearBUTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)               
{                                         
mainPassword.setText("");
encryptTXT.setText("");
decryptTXT.setText("");
encryptKey.setText("");
decryptKey.setText("");
}                                        

private void decryptBUTActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)     
{                                           
    int textLength=decryptTXT.getText().length();
    ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
    String text=decryptTXT.getText();
    int count=1;
    String key=decryptKey.getText();
    if(key.isEmpty())
    {
        encryptTXT.setText(""+"INVALID KEY");
    }
    else
    {
        int key2=Integer.parseInt(key);
        for(int i=0;i<textLength;i++)
        {
            if(text.charAt(i)=='['||text.charAt(i)==','||text.charAt(i)==']')
            {
                count=count+1;
            }
            else if(count%2==0)
            {
                char number=text.charAt(i);
                char number2=text.charAt(i+1);
                int num=(int)number;
                int num2=(int)number2;
                int num3=num;
                int num4=num3+num2-15;
                int num5=num4+key2;
                char letter2=(char)num5;
                list.add(letter2);
                count=count+1;
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
        Object[] obj=(list.toArray());
        String out=Arrays.toString(obj);
        encryptTXT.setText(out);
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit: Due date removed as this is not germane to the coding issue at hand.

Comment: Slip of the mouse sorry guys didn't mean to offend.

Comment: Can you solve this outside of Swing? I suggest making a small test program that has no GUI code but instead uses some test Strings and default values, information you would have gotten from your Swing text components, and then try to solve this in a simple milieu rather than solve it in a complex one. Then if you're still stuck,  you can post your small compilable and runnable test program and we can help modify it and get it to work.

Comment: just a suggestion : dont attack difficult problems like encryption if you're new to programming. Ever. The only thing you'll achieve is confusion. Start with hello-world apps and work your way up from there, everything else is assured failure

Answer (score 1):

***Solved***

**This is how I encrypted my text:**

```
int encryptLength=encryptTXT.getText().length();
String key=encryptKey.getText();
String text="";
if(key.isEmpty())
{
    decryptTXT.setText(""+"INVALID KEY");
}
else
{
    int key2=Integer.parseInt(key);
    for(int i=0;i<encryptLength;i++)
    {
        int letter = encryptTXT.getText().toLowerCase().charAt(i);
        int letterCiphered = (letter-key2);
        text=text+letterCiphered+" ";
    }
    decryptTXT.setText(""+text);
}
```

**This is how I decrypted my text**

```
try
{
String text=decryptTXT.getText();
String key=decryptKey.getText();
String[] decrypt=text.split(" ");
String sentance="";
if(key.isEmpty())
{
    encryptTXT.setText(""+"INVALID KEY");
}
else
{
    int key2=Integer.parseInt(key);
    for(int i=0;i<decrypt.length;i++)
    {
        int number=Integer.parseInt(decrypt[i]);
        char letter=(char)(number+key2);
        sentance=sentance+letter;
    }
    encryptTXT.setText(""+sentance);
}
}
catch(NumberFormatException e)
{
    encryptTXT.setText(""+"Please enter a valid encoded message");
}
```

Thanks for all the help guys turned out a lot simpler than I thought.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your encryption just shifts every character of the message by a given value.

```
 int letterCiphered= (letter-key2);
```

To decipher such a message you should shift each character of the cipher by the same value but in the other direction.

```
 int letter= (letterCiphered+key2);
```

The decryption function you have in the code does something else entirely.

update following the comments:

If i understand correctly you want to convert a string of ascii values to the text they represent.

To parse the input string, if it's a simple format, you could just use `String.split()` read about it.
To convert a textual representation of a number to an actual number you could use `Integer.parseInt()`.
Finally, to turn an integer ascii value to a character you only need to cast `char c = (char)97;`

Parse the input to identify each ascii value, convert each value to an integer and cast it to a character, then just concatenate the characters to a string.

Comment: Yes it's a Caesar Cipher but then the letters are converted to their corresponding ASCII values and stored in an Array this Array is then Displayed in my JTextField and sorry I was busy messing around with some ideas when I posted this I know how to decode it. My problem is not the actual deciphering it's more on how do I fetch only pairs of ASCII values from entered text and convert them to text (chars) if you follow the URL you would see what I mean, it doesn't cipher the text but it does convert the char to ASCII and back.

Comment: bytes can be converted to chars by simply casting them to it: (char). Or a String can be formed from a byte array via `new String(myByteArray)`. Perhaps you want to use a byte array and not an int array.

Comment: I was reading something earlier about String Methods for pattern matching 2 looked promising `match()` and `replace()` could those be a possibility as I said I don't really understand it though so I couldn't implement it.

Comment: What would be really great is if I could do a JTextField version of `System.println()` that would make things a lot easier.

Comment: @ChaseVsGodzilla You want something like JTextArea.append(...).

Answer (score -3):

```
package cipher;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cipher {

    public static final String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    public static final String ADDRESS = "C:\\Users\\abhati\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Cipher\\encode.txt";
    public static final String LOCATE = "C:\\Users\\abhati\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Cipher\\decode.enc";


    public static int MenuOption() throws Exception
    {
       int option;
 do{

        System.out.println("    +++++++++++++++++++\n    +   1. Encrypt    +");
        System.out.println("    +++++++++++++++++++\n    +   2. Decrypt    +");
        System.out.println("    +++++++++++++++++++\n    +   3.  Quit      + \n    +++++++++++++++++++");
        System.out.println("\nWhat would you like to do?");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
        option = input.nextInt();

        switch(option)
        {
            case 1:     encrypt();
                        break;

            case 2:     decrypt();
                        break;       

            case 3:     System.exit(0);
                        break;
            default: System.out.println("WRONG INPUT ??? PLEASE SELECT THE OPTION \n");
        }

    } while(option != 3);
              return option;   
 }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
      System.out.println("Hello to Change Your text into cipher text!!!!\n");
      System.out.println("Put your text file in root folder.\n");
      MenuOption();
      System.out.println();
    }


    public static void encrypt() throws Exception {

     String ex;   
     FileReader in=null;
     FileWriter out = null;
      try {

          File file = new File(ADDRESS);
          in = new FileReader(file);
          file.getName();

          ex=getFileExtensionE(file);

          if(ex.equals("txt"))
         {
         out = new FileWriter(LOCATE);

         Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in); 
         System.out.println("What is the value for the key?");
         int key = input2.nextInt();


        Scanner input3 = new Scanner(in);
        while (input3.hasNext()) {
        String line = input3.nextLine();
        line = line.toLowerCase();
        String crypt = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        int position = ALPHABET.indexOf(line.charAt(i));
        int keyValue = (key + position) % 26;
        char replace = ALPHABET.charAt(keyValue);
        crypt += replace;
        }
        out.write(""+crypt);
        System.out.println(""+crypt);
        }
        input3.close();
        System.out.println("\nDATA ENCRYPTED\n");
         }
        else 
         {
         System.out.println("DOESN'T ENCRYPTED!");   
                 }
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("\n NO FILE FOUND WITH THIS NAME!!!");   
    }
        finally {
         if (in != null) {
            in.close();
         }
         if (out != null) {
            out.close();
         }
      }
}

    public static void decrypt() throws Exception {

      String ex;
      FileReader in = null;
      FileWriter out = null;
      try {

         File file = new File(LOCATE);
         in = new FileReader(file);
         file.getName(); 

         ex=getFileExtensionD(file);

          if(ex.equals("enc"))
         {
         out = new FileWriter("encrpted_DATA.txt");

         Scanner input4 = new Scanner(System.in); 
         System.out.println("What is the value for the key?");
         int key = input4.nextInt();                    

        Scanner input5 = new Scanner(in);
        while (input5.hasNext()) {
        String line = input5.nextLine();
        line = line.toLowerCase();
        String decrypt = "";

        for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        int position = ALPHABET.indexOf(line.charAt(i));
        int keyValue = (position - key) % 26;
         if (keyValue < 0)
            {
                keyValue = ALPHABET.length() + keyValue;
            }
        char replace = ALPHABET.charAt(keyValue);
        decrypt += replace;
        }
        out.write(""+decrypt);
        System.out.println(""+decrypt);
        }
        input5.close();
        System.out.println("\nDATA DECRYPTED\n");

        }
        else 
         {
          System.out.println("DOESN'T DECRYPTED!");   
         }
      }  catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("\n NO FILE FOUND WITH THIS NAME!!!");   
    }
         finally {
         if (in != null) {
            in.close();
         }
         if (out != null) {
            out.close();
         }
    }
}

    public static String getFileExtensionE(File file) {
    String name = file.getName();
    try {
        return name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}

    public static String getFileExtensionD(File file) {
    String name = file.getName();
    try {
        return name.substring(name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }
}  
}
```